# importing class and its function from another file

Tags: python, class

I am having little problem with importing classes in python. My work flow goes like this

```
index.py

    class Template:

        def header():
        def body():
        def form():
        def footer():

display.py
```

I want to call function `header()`, `body()` and `footer ()` in my `display.py` page. Will anyone make me clear about this issue in python. Thanks for your concern.

Index file--- [Index.py][1]

[1]: http://pastebin.com/qNB53KTE and display.py -- "http://pastebin.com/vRsJumzq"

Comment: I recommend you to read up on more Python tutorials. Plenty of examples out there. `=]`

Comment: Also, please note that the Python style guide (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends using CapWords in class names, not all lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the code! we couldn't have figured it out otherwise. Now go accept more answers. =3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your index file you create a `HtmlTemplate` object and call all the methods on it. Since this code is not contained in any other block, it gets executed when you import the module. You either need to remove it or check to see if the file is being run from the command line.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    objx=HtmlTemplate()
    objx.Header()
    objx.Body()
    objx.Form()
    objx.Footer()
    objx.CloseHtml()
```

Answer (score 8):

What have you tried? The following would be normal way of using methods of `Template` class after import.

```
from index import Template

t = Template()
t.header()
t.body()
t.footer()
```

**ETA:** at the end of your `index.py` file (lines 99-105) you're calling all the functions from the above-defined `Template` class. That's why you're seeing duplicates.

Comment: i have tried the same like u did. but i always get repetition like 2 times body() etc

Comment: @user: you're probably calling methods from the `Template`'s `__init__`. Otherwise, there is nothing in this code that would produce duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Okay, I see what your problem is, given your code.

You're calling the following:

```
## Calling all the functions of the class template with object (objx)
objx=HtmlTemplate()
objx.Header()
objx.Body()
objx.Form()
objx.Footer()
objx.CloseHtml()
```

And then in your `display.py`:

```
t = HtmlTemplate()
t.Header()
t.Body()
```

See how `Body()` gets called twice?

As a footnote, you should use lowercase for method names, and Capital words for classes as you're doing now. It's a good convention. I greatly recommend it.

You should simply construct the object once in `display.py` and call all the methods.

Comment: yeah every function has self parameter which im aware of

Comment: What other problems do you have? Can you provide us with more code?

Comment: Like my workflow above, i have index.py file [with given class and fucntions] and from index.py file i want to pass values from form() to display.py. In display.py i need to call only header(), body() and footer(). But i am doing same things like u guys said, but got repetition in the display page. Display page goes like this- header(), body(), form(), footer() and again body() and some other cotent from display page.

Comment: @user: we need to see the actual code of your template class and its methods. We're not psychics.

Comment: @user343934: If you call `body()` twice, then surely you expect the output of `body()` twice...

Comment: @user343934: Umm, you called `body()` again?

Comment: @user343934: Thanks for the pastebin. See how easy that was? `:]`

Comment: I mean in the display.py i can find body, form repetitions

Comment: @user343934: Because everything gets "run" when you import it. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I believe you are asking how to import the `template` class in another script. The `import` statement is what you need:

```
from index import template

foo = template()

foo.header()
foo.body()
foo.footer()
```

Comment: there's a couple of typos here, that render your answer completely nonsensical.

Comment: @Sil: The first revision of my answer was indeed quite buggy. If it was not for the annoying "are you human" feature, the typos would have been fixed before your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the following code at the top and the bottom of `index.py`:

```
cgitb.enable()
print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/msa.css\" >"

# [...]

## Calling all the functions of the class template with object (objx)
objx=HtmlTemplate()
# [...]      
objx.CloseHtml()
```

This will be called each time you `import index`.

To prevent this happening, put it in a block thus:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cgitb.enable()
    print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
    print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/msa.css\" >"

    # [...]

    ## Calling all the functions of the class template with object (objx)
    objx=HtmlTemplate()
    # [...]      
    objx.CloseHtml()
```

...or **better still put this code functions** that can be called from elsewhere.

Comment: It seems working but still with one error that in display.py i receive "Content-type: text/html " on the top

Comment: Yes... that code is pulled in with the module too. I've included that in my revised answer.

Comment: @user343934: Yeah, because you should have put the content type also into a HTML-proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me:

```
class1(unittest.TestCase):
   def method1(self)

class2(unittest.TestCase):
   def method2(self):
      instance_name = class1("method1")
      instance_name.method1()
```